# Forgot how to delete folders with subfolders in dos.Can you help?

Tags: dos

I thought I would never use dos again.I wrong I was/am.

I am trying to delete a folder with this structure
"MyFolder"
    AnotherFolder
        AnotherFolder 
    Folder1
    Folder2 
       Folder21 etc...

I do this 
get the cmd prompt
go to my folder
cd MyFolder
type attrib -R - A -S -H C:\MyFolder (remove all attributes eg readonly etc..)
del myfolder

but this does not cut it.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
I want to remove all attribute restrictions on folder and subfolders and delete
Any suggestions
thanks a lot

Comment: this is better asked on superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use RMDIR /S /Q  instead